Check for prime number
I'm using python to check if a number is prime or not, but when I write 15 it gave me True
import math
def isPrime(i):
    if i == 2 or i == 3:
        return True
    if i < 2:
        return False
    if  i % 2 == 0:
        return False
    for j in range(3,int(math.sqrt(i))):
        if i % j == 0:
            return False
    return True
while True:
    print(isPrime(int(input())))

Are there any solutions?

int(sqrt(15)) is 3, and range won't even check this one. Fix: range(3, int(sqrt(i+1))+1)

Note that the same error (false positive) occurs for other numbers, e.g 9. You need to learn debugging

for j in range(3,int(math.sqrt(i))+1, 2): is better

int(math.sqrt(15)) equals 3. So you're trying to do:
for j in range(3, 3):
    ...

range(3, 3) is an empty sequence, so this for-loop doesn't execute, and thus it skips straight to returning True.
A simple solution to this would be incrementing your end value by 1 so that your for-loop runs:
for j in range(3, int(math.sqrt(i)) + 1):
    if i % j == 0:
        return False


step 2 improves performance
